# D3 add zoom and pan to map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js, zooming

a newb here.

I'm trying to add zoom and pan to [this map](http://airwwwave.com/inter/registrations-slider-v5/index.html). I've copied this code from the "Zooming and panning a map" section of [this page](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/03/a-simple-d3js-map-explained.html) from d3noob's site:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .on("zoom",function() {
        g.attr("transform","translate("+ 
            d3.event.translate.join(",")+")scale("+d3.event.scale+")");
        g.selectAll("path")  
            .attr("d", path.projection(projection)); 
});

svg.call(zoom)
```

And pasted it with minor adjustments at line 163:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .on("zoom",function() {
      svg.append("g").attr("transform", 
        "translate(" + d3.event.translate.join(",") + 
        ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")"); 
      svg.append("g").selectAll("path")  
          .attr("d", myPath.projection(myProjection));
  });    

svg.call(zoom)
```

But, there is no zoom or pan behavior and no console errors. What am I missing? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. The problem was that I wasn't zooming on the correct containing element. Once I set it this way, it worked great.

- make a `<g>` inside the main `svg`
- put all the map stuff inside that `<g>`
- set the zoom function to translate and scale that `<g>`
- but set the `.call` on the `svg` not the `<g>`